# Trim filenames after a set number of characters in a directory

Tags: string, powershell, filenames, trim

Newbie to PowerShell, but keen to learn.
I want to remove the characters form filenames after a set number of characters. For example if I have these filenames in a directory of .pdf files:

```
4616_A411_P05_Ground Floor Plan Zone 6
4616_A412_P06_Ground Floor Plan Zone 7
4616_A413_P04_Ground Floor Plan Zone 8
4616_A414_P04_Ground Floor Plan Zone 9
4616_A415_P05_Ground Floor Plan Zone 10
4616_A416_P04_Ground Floor Plan Zone 11
4616_A616_P03_Loading Door Details_Elevation_Sheet 1
4616_A617_P03_Loading Door Details_Elevation_Sheet 2
4616_A618_P03_Loading Door Details_Elevation_Sheet 3
...
```

And I would like to rename them to:

```
4616_A411
4616_A412
4616_A413
4616_A414
4616_A415
4616_A416
4616_A616
4616_A617
4616_A618
...
```

Basically the trim all filenames after 9 characters in the files names of a directory

Seen lots of examples how to use the Trim function the trim leading characters and special characters, but not after specified number of characters.
Note. the filenames could be longer but would have retain the first 9 characters that need to be kept the rest trimmed.

Could not get Trim function to work correctly

Comment: Got any attempt so far that you have tried? If so, please add it to your question

Comment: Search for examples of the String.Substring() method rather than trim ()...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.